# How you use BluetoothA2dp class in Xamarin

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, xamarin, a2dp

I am trying to controll Bluetooth connection to a device using the A2DP profile.
In native Java Development for Android, devs make use of BluetoothA2dp class to make a connection.

There is a class called the same in Xamarin - BluetoothA2dp. But I can't seem to understand how to initialize an instance of it, since it has no constructor.

How can I create a connection with the help of that class port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the BluetoothA2dp class directly. As per the Android documentation...

> BluetoothA2dp is a proxy object for controlling the Bluetooth A2DP
>   Service via IPC. Use getProfileProxy(Context,
>   BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener, int) to get the BluetoothA2dp proxy
>   object.

You should use `BluetoothAdapter.GetProfileProxy` to initiate a connection to the A2DP proxy object.

```
BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.GetProfileProxy(this, serviceListener, ProfileType.A2dp);
```

The `serviceListener` argument in the method call above needs to be an instance of a class which implements `IBluetoothProfileServiceListener`, in which you can then access the proxy object through the OnServiceConnected method.

```
public void OnServiceConnected(ProfileType profile, IBluetoothProfile proxy)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Well, we've "signed up for" `OnServiceConnected` and when we manually connect A2DP profile (to a remote device) from a system bluetooth connection activity, the event isn't getting fired. At least in theory, when should the method `OnServiceConnected` be getting executed?

Comment: `OnServiceConnected` is called when the AD2P proxy object is connected to the service, not when devices are connected. So it will be called soon after the call to `GetProfileProxy`. I've tested a quick activity with the code I posted above and it calls the method as expected. I'd need to see some code to advise really.

Comment: Although a dev trying this is saying that on his machine OnServiceConnected isn't beig called, I think this answers the question about how to use this class, so I am marking it as a correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The class "BluetoothA2DP" has been provided in Xamarin version 5.0 to 5.2, [**refer to link**](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/ios/api_changes/from_5.0_to_5.2/)

Since "BluetoothA2DP" is **sealed** class, it cannot be inherited. You can only used it through its instances.

You need to override its **"GetConnectionState"** or **"GetDevicesMatchingConnectionStates"** methods to connect particular device.

Probably, the best you can do is try to extend the functionality of **"BluetoothA2DP"** using your own extension method.

Suppose your **"BluetoothA2DP"** class be like :

```
public sealed class BluetoothA2dp : Java.Lang.Object,   IBluetoothProfile, IDisposable {
    public ProfileState GetConnectionState (BluetoothDevice device)  {
        return some_device_configs;
    }
}
```

Then your own class that extends **"BluetoothA2DP"** class functionality as :

```
public static class MyClassExtender
{
    public static void ExtendedTest(this BluetoothA2DP instance)
    {
        instance.GetConnectionState();        
    }
}
```

Then use ExtendedTest() method to utilize **"BluetoothA2DP"** class.

Hope this should work :)

You can **[refer here](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp)** for full API Docs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Ok, I've added an extension method as you demonstarated. If I had an isntance of the BluetoothA2DP I could be calling ExtendedTest() from it. But since I don't have an instance of the class, I can't access the ExtendedTest() method using the BluetoothA2dp as a static class. How can I call the ExtendedTest() correctly?

Comment: You need to create instance of "MyClassExtender" class and through it call the "ExtendedTest()"

Comment: This advice is incorrect. You can't 'override' `GetConnectionState` as it's not an abstract or virtual method, and the class is sealed anyway, so can't be inherited from. Also, `MyClassExtender` above is a static class, so can't be instantiated as you've suggested. The syntax above is for creating an extension method to the `BluetoothA2DP` class, of which you would need an instance. See my answer for how to get access to the A2DP proxy object.